# Como filtrar os cenários que executarão @BeforeScenario?

Tags: testes, demoiselle

Tenho uma série de cenários no demoiselle-behave, e quero filtrar aqueles que devem executar um método marcado com `@BeforeScenario`.

No *cucumber-jvm*, faço assim:

```demoiselle
Funcionalidade: Acesso
@web
Cenário: Autenticar com sucesso
    // Passos
```

...

```demoiselle
@Before("@web")
public void antesDosCenariosWeb() {...}
```

E ele entende que todos os cenários/funcionalidades marcadas com aquela tag, executarão aquele método.